# Restrict PHP access to root folders?

Tags: php, root, restrict

Im making sort of a service where people can upload PHP files and they get their own directory.

Is there a way to prevent any way the PHP can access the root of the server? and just stay in the bounderies of its folder?

Comment: Beware of a common vulnerability in this sort of feature: make sure that the files users upload cannot be executed.  Especially if they upload, say, a `.php` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`open_basedir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) directive does just that :

> Limit the files that can be opened by
>   PHP to the specified directory-tree,
>   including the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

The most secure would be to [chroot Apache and PHP](http://www.securityfocus.com/infocus/1706).